# How do I do logging in Haskell?

Tags: logging, haskell, monads

I'm attempting to use HSlogger to get some information about my program. So I add the following line to my function

```
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Bits
import Data.Int
import Data.ByteString.Parser

import System.Log.Logger
import System.Log.Handler.Syslog


importFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either String (PESFile ))
importFile n = do
     warningM "MyApp.Component2" "Something Bad is about to happen."
     ...
```

And that works fine, because the function is inside IO. 
However when I add a similar line to the following function:

```
...
parsePES :: Parser PESFile
parsePES = do
        header <- string "#PES"
        warningM "parsing header"
        ...
        return (PESFile ...)
```

I get a type error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Parser a0'
                with actual type `String -> IO ()'
    In the return type of a call of `warningM'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: warningM "parsing header"
    In the expression:
      do { header <- string "#PES";
           warningM "parsing header";
        ...
```

And I totally understand why - parsePES is in the Parser monad, not the IO monad.
What I don't understand is what to do about it. Do I need a monad transformer so I can stack the Parser monad and the IO monad together? How do I go about that?

Comment: Haskell is much cooler, BUT also has a steeper learning curve than any other language I've learned.

Comment: Where is `Parser` coming from? Are you using Parsec?

Comment: I'm using Data.ByteString.Parser. (updated code to reflect that)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First, a quick disclaimer: "logging" doesn't usually make sense in general Haskell code, because it assumes some sort of sequential execution that may or may not be meaningful. Make sure you distinguish between *logging how the program executes* and *logging what values are computed*. In strict imperative languages these are mostly the same, but in Haskell they aren't.

That said, it sounds like you want to log based on values being computed, in the context of an already sequential and stateful computation, which pretty much works the same as logging in most other languages does. However, you do need the monad to support some means of doing so. It looks like the parser you're using is [from the HCodecs package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HCodecs/0.2/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Parser.html), which seems to be relatively limited, doesn't allow `IO`, and isn't defined as a monad transformer.

Honestly my advice would be to consider using a different parsing library. [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) tends to be kind of the default choice, and I think [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) is popular for specific purposes (which might include what you're doing). Either would let you add logging much more easily: Parsec is a monad transformer, so you can put it on top of `IO` and then use `liftIO` as needed, whereas attoparsec is designed around incremental processing, so you can chunk your input and log aspects of the processing (though logging inside the actual parser may be more awkward). There are other choices as well but I don't know enough of the details to make a recommendation. Most parser combinator-based libraries tend to have fairly similar designs, so I'd expect porting your code would be straightforward.

A final option, if you *really* want to stick to what you've got, would be to look at the implementation of the parsing library you're using now and roll your own `IO`-oriented version of it. But that's probably not ideal.

---

Also, as an addendum, if you what you're really after isn't actually logging but just tracing the execution of your program as part of development, you might find the debugger built into GHCi to be more helpful, or good old-fashioned printf debugging via [the Debug.Trace module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html).

---

**Edit**: Okay, sounds like you have plausible reasons to consider rolling your own variation. What you roughly want here is a `ParserT` monad transformer. Here's the current definition of `Parser`:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { unParser :: S -> Either String (a, S) }
```

The type `S` is the parser state. Note that this is roughly a hard-coded version of `StateT S (Either String) a`:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

...where `Either String` is being treated as an error monad. The `ErrorT` monad transformer does the same thing:

```
newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT { runErrorT :: m (Either e a) }
```

So where the current type is equivalent to `StateT S (ErrorT String Identity)`, what you want would be `StateT S (ErrorT String IO)`.

It looks like most of the functions in the module aren't messing with the internals of the `Parser` monad, so you *should* be able to simply replace the type definitions, supply the appropriate type class instances, write your own `runParser` function, and be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your very considered answer. I chose the parser from the HCodecs package because it supports all sorts of slightly unusual numeric formats like Word24 and Word16 in both little and big endian versions. It turns out I need those, and I'm not too keen on doing the bit twiddling by hand. If attoparsec supported those, I would give it a shot instead. Otherwise, I'll probably be rolling my own based on the HCodecs version.

Comment: @nont: Ahh, that certainly makes sense. I'm not sufficiently well-versed on what options exist to say if anything else offers the same support. If you do roll your own, you probably want to start by looking into monad transformers, I'm going to edit a few useful tips on that into my answer that may help you get started.

Comment: I think your addendum about Debug.Trace is what I'm really after as I'm building my module. trace does the trick. Thanks! I'm glad for your whole explanation, as generic logging would be helpful too, and its not something I know how to do.

Comment: @nont: Ah, okay. Well, the info about monad transformers is there if you want it, but `Debug.Trace` is often enough when you just need to see what's happening in non-production code. Like I said, it's just old-fashioned printf debugging, like I used long, long ago before discovering debuggers. :)

Comment: @nont: Haha, just glad I could help! You're absolutely correct that Haskell has a steeper learning curve, but I think it's fun and worth the effort, so I do what I can to help ease the way...

Answer (score 30):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [Logger Haskell framework](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logger-0.1.0.0).

Although McCann's answer is greatly detailed, it does not tell, that Haskell was lacking a general purpose logging framework at the time the question was asked. The HSLogger is a standard now, but it provides very basic logging functionality while being slow and not extensible. To be clear, here are some defects of HSLogger:

1. It is slow. By being slow I mean, that every time you log a message it
   parses (in a very simple way) a string describing the origin of the log and uses some existential datatypes under the hood, which have to introduce some performance overhead at runtime.
2. It does not allow logging in other monads than IO, so you have to use `WriterT` or other solutions not to mess your code.
3. It is not extensible - you cannot create your own priority levels, define custom behaviours (like inter-thread logging) or compile time logs filtering.
4. It does not provide some information, like line numbers or file names where the logs were placed. And of course it is very hard to extend it to support such information.

That being said I would love to introduce the [Logger Haskell framework](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logger-0.1.0.0). It allows for efficient & extensible logging, including:

1. logging in sequential pure code (performing as well as using `WriterT` monad)
2. advanced message filtering (including compile-time filtering)
3. inter-thread logging ability
4. provides `TemplateHaskell` interface allowing logging additional details, like file numbers or module names
5. is very easily extensible - all the features are created as extensions to a simple `BaseLogger`, which cannot do anything sensible. To be clear - the filtering functionality is created in less than 20 lines as a logger-transformer and you can define your own transformers. How to do it is described in [the documentation](https://github.com/wdanilo/haskell-logger).
6. Provides colored output on all platforms by default.

But the library is pretty new, so it can lack some needed functionality. The good information is, that you can create this functionality easily by yourself or help us improve it by reporting issues on GitHub.

The logger is developed internally by the company I'm working at ([luna-lang.org](https://luna-lang.org)) and is used inside a compiler we are creating.

Comment: great docs! I think you need to put an empty line after "There are few things to not here:" in `System.Log` to format the list (and fix the typo to "note").

Comment: @samboosalis: Thank you! The most recent documentation is available on github (https://github.com/wdanilo/haskell-logger) and its nicer formatted there. I'll update the docs on hackage when new version comes out. Thank you for your attention and help! :) If you like, you can always help us and change anything you want in the docs and create pull request - this would be very helpful in the future! :)

Comment: no worries! In which case, I'll just perform my own suggestion. as a new Haskeller, I've been thinking about adding/fixing documentation for packages I use, to give back in a small way. of course, I have to make sure I understand the package, though just adding examples I guess always works :-)