# Structuring a Haskell program

Tags: haskell

Im trying to structure a haskell module as best i can and this is what i have come up with.

The inputs can be Fix or Twitter
and the output from the parsers can be maybe output, I want to tag the output from the parsers as either Structured or Unstructured.

Is this the right type signatures? Am i using the maybe monad instance class correctly? Is this the right way to handle side effects in haskell?

```
module Parsers.Parser(
      handle
    ) where

data Input = FIX Text
        | Twitter Text

data Output = StructuredDataEvent Quote 
            | UnStructuredDataEvent  Text

handle :: Input -> Output
handle (FIX r)      = fixParser  r >>=   StructuredDataEvent  
handle (Twitter r)  = twitterParser  r >>=  UnStructuredDataEvent

sideEffects:: Output -> Output
sideEffects   a = LogEventToDatabase a

instance Monad Maybe where  
    return x = Just $ sideEffects x  
    Nothing >>= f = Nothing  
    Just x >>= f  = f $ sideEffects x  
    fail _ =  Nothing
```

Comment: `Maybe` is already an instance of `Monad`. It's also generally unclear what you're talking about. Does this code compile?

Comment: If this was compiling and working i would be less inclined to come onto stack overflow....

this isnt a standard maybe monad...Im logging stuff to the database

return x = Just $ sideEffects x  
Just x >>= f  = f $ sideEffects x  

My question is whether this is the correct approach to handle side effects

And because >>= can return nothing is:
handle :: Input -> Output
or 
handle :: Input -> Maybe Output
the correct signature

Comment: What does `LogEventToDatabase` do? This probably doesn't pass the monad laws. To answer your question: no, this is not the right way to handle side effects in Haskell.

Comment: (LogEventToDatabase a) Inserts contents of "a" to the database and returns a.

Comment: @Devitect It does this outside of IO?

Answer (score 1):

`handle` should be of type `Input -> IO Output` if you really want to do side-effects.

But it's better to write a pure parser that keeps a list of all your error messages around. If they are just `String`s, and for example [using the Writer monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more):

```
handle :: Input -> Writer [String] Output
```

Also, have you considered [using Parsec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311338/214446), which is monad transformer?